# trigger para cambiar un estatus

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Estoy trabajando con triggers, soy nuevo en el tema y quiero crear un trigger que compare la fecha de prox. actualización, y la fecha actual, es decir la de hoy, y cuento con una tabla tblEstado en el cual tengo 3 posibles estados en un rango, vigente de 9-6 días, por vencer de 5-3 días y vencido de 2-1 día, cuento con un modulo en el cual visualizo el estado, y esta como foránea el id de la tabla estado en la tabla del modulo, entonces lo que debe hacer es cambiar el estado dependiendo el rango de días al comparar las dos fechas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando con esta sentencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es la parte del código:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.RecursosVigencia
   ON  tbl_Recurso
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  --se declaran las variables 
  DECLARE @iIdRecurso INT
  DECLARE @iIdEstadoActualizacion INT
  DECLARE @dtDiaActual DATETIME
  DECLARE @dtFechaProxActualizacion DATETIME
  DECLARE @dtFechaUltimaActualizacion DATETIME
  DECLARE @lActivo BIT


  --Se obtienen los valores del regisstro 
  SET @iIdRecurso = (SELECT iIdRecurso  FROM inserted) --traemos el id de la tabla recurso
  SET @cSemaforo = (SELECT cSemaforo FROM inserted) 
  SET @iIdEstadoActualizacion = (SELECT iIdEstadoActualizacion FROM inserted)
  SELECT @dtFechaProxActualizacion = (SELECT dtFechaProxActualizacion FROM inserted) 
  SELECT @dtDiaActual = GETDATE() FROM inserted


    --se consulta todos los recursos
    SELECT * FROM tbl_Recurso

    IF( @dtFechaProxActualizacion > @dtDiaActual)
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE tbl_Recurso SET cSemaforo = @cSemaforo WHERE iIdRecurso LIKE  @cSemaforo 

        INSERT INTO tbl_HistorialRecurso (iIdEstadoActualizacion, cSemaforo ) (SELECT iIdEstadoActualizacion, cSemaforo FROM deleted WHERE  iIdEstadoActualizacion = deleted.cSemaforo)
    END  
END
GO
PRINT 'Se crea de manera correcta el TRIGGER dbo.RecursosVigencia'
```

Comment: Hola seria mejor si pusieras la sentencia como código, como imagen es mas difícil ayudarte.
Saludos

Comment: Tu código no hace mucha lógica. Podrías compartir datos de prueba y los resultados esperados basados en esos datos de prueba? También la operación que esperas que desencadene el trigger.